# send pdf from database through email in php mailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdf

I am trying to send a pdf file from database through php Mailer. when I fetch the file from database and save it in $document and echo it. it echos correctly. But when I put the same $document in addAttachment function the email sends but with no attachments. Here is my code

```
 require("PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");
 $link = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());


 $email = new PHPMailer();

$email->From      = 'info@email.com';

$email->FromName  = 'xxxxxxxx';

$email->Subject   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$email->Body      = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$email->AddAddress( 'saad@gmail.com' );

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT file FROM pdf WHERE cnic = 1610209991607", $link) or die("There is an error in the connection");

$document1=mysql_result($result, 0, 'file'); 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');

//echo $document1;//it works correctly

  //$file_to_attach = '$document1';

  //$email->AddAttachment($doucment1, 'PayRoll.pdf');//it send the attachment when I attach the file from a folder like AddAttachment(my.pdf);

    return $email->Send();`
```

Comment: please print the value of `$document1` I suspect that the value is NOT the absolute path to file and instead just the file name...no one here will trust your judgement, the code isn't working therefore your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: header() call makes no snes here

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I've printed the value of $document1 and it works fine when there is no code below it. 

If this approach is not  right. Can you guide me to the right one?